# Dynamics CRM sub grid defaulting to creating new record vs. lookup existing records

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are using Dynamics CRM 2016.  I am using the Account entity to track both customers and competitors.  I created a new 1:N relationship between Opportunity and Account and named it Account_Competitors.  I put a sub grid on my opportunity form titled "Competitors" and configured it to show related Account_Competitors.  When I click the "+" button I get a quick create form. I want the "Add Existing" behavior.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If the lookup to Opportunity on Account is business required, you will experience what you see now (which does not sound optimal).

If you change the lookup to be optional instead, the initial behavior when pressing the "+" button in a subgrid will be to initiate the "Add Existing" behavior.

With that said, it sounds a bit strange to have a 1:N-relationship for this. In this way a Competitor-Account can only be associated with a single Opportunity. I would suggest looking into using the standard Competitor entity, or using an N:N relationship instead.

Answer (score 2):

To control the behavior of the new record button on subgrids, look at the child entity being selected in the subgrid..If the lookup field for the parent is required, the user will get a “new record” form when clicking the + button. If the lookup field for the parent entity is not required on the child entity, the user will get the lookup field to “add existing.”

For more details with example you can look at http://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/05/sub-grid-add-action-behavior-in-dynamics-crm/